# Google Maps Places API - Autocomplete city suggestions, same city, different place_ids?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm creating a web application with a city autocomplete suggestion field using the Google Maps Place API. Once a city is selected I capture the *place_id* and write it to my database attached to my object.

Currently the Google Maps Places API is returning different place_id's for the same city suggestion when searched from a different location?

The following query returns a different place_id for the result **'Brisbane, Queensland, Australia'** depending on where it's searched from.

QUERY → https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Brisbane&types=(cities)&key=AIzaSyBylZrzm8TS-jfEcBgyY9Um15NCDADLt44

Searched from Brisbane: place_id = ChIJuyD2XARakWsRwITe81qjAgU

Searched from Melbourne: place_id = ChIJM9KTrJpXkWsRQK_e81qjAgQ

Similar, but different :(

I thought specifying the *types* parameter as '*(cities)*' would keep all results consistent.

Is there another parameter or change to the query that will make it bulletproof?

Comment: I dont know what you call 'bullet-proof' but the only thing I can say is that place_id is unique so it cannot be the same.